# EntityFramework 6 model generation very slow with SQL-Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, vmware

I use Visual Studio 2015 Professional with Sql Server 2016 and EntityFramework 6.
After wondering about the slow performance of model generation I found in the class **EntityStoreSchemaGeneratorDatabaseSchemaLoader** the method `IEnumerable<DataRow> LoadDataTable`.

The execution of the command need sometimes more than 2 minutes, whereas with older versions of sql server it takes milliseconds.

```
using (EntityCommand command = CreateFilteredCommand(_connection, sql, null, queryTypes, new List<EntityStoreSchemaFilterEntry>(filters), filterAliases))
{
    using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
...
```

Does anyone know, why the ExecuteReader is so extremly slow? It is not a problem with CPU or memory. **Maybe it is important to say, that SQL-Server 2016 runs in VM-Ware!**

**UPDATE**

This statements runs for minutes in SQL-Server 2016, in 2012 it takes milliseconds.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[UnionAll1].[Ordinal] AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[CatalogName] AS [CatalogName], 
[Extent1].[SchemaName] AS [SchemaName], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[UnionAll1].[Name] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll1].[IsNullable] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll1].[TypeName] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll1].[MaxLength] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll1].[Precision] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll1].[DateTimePrecision] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll1].[Scale] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll1].[IsIdentity] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll1].[IsStoreGenerated] AS [C10], 
CASE WHEN ([Project5].[C2] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Project5].[C2] END AS [C11]
FROM   (
        SELECT
        quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(TABLE_NAME) [Id]
        ,   TABLE_CATALOG [CatalogName]
        ,   TABLE_SCHEMA [SchemaName]
        ,   TABLE_NAME    [Name]
        FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE
        TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE''
      ) AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[Ordinal] AS [Ordinal], 
    [Extent2].[IsNullable] AS [IsNullable], 
    [Extent2].[TypeName] AS [TypeName], 
    [Extent2].[MaxLength] AS [MaxLength], 
    [Extent2].[Precision] AS [Precision], 
    [Extent2].[DateTimePrecision] AS [DateTimePrecision], 
    [Extent2].[Scale] AS [Scale], 
    [Extent2].[IsIdentity] AS [IsIdentity], 
    [Extent2].[IsStoreGenerated] AS [IsStoreGenerated], 
    0 AS [C1], 
    [Extent2].[ParentId] AS [ParentId]
    FROM (
          SELECT
          quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME) + quotename(c.COLUMN_NAME) [Id]
          ,   quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)                             [ParentId]
          ,   c.COLUMN_NAME   [Name]
          ,   c.ORDINAL_POSITION [Ordinal]
          ,   CAST( CASE c.IS_NULLABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN 1 WHEN ''NO'' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END as bit) [IsNullable]
          ,   CASE
          WHEN c.DATA_TYPE in (''varchar'', ''nvarchar'', ''varbinary'') and
          c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN
          c.DATA_TYPE + ''(max)''
          ELSE
          c.DATA_TYPE
          END
          as [TypeName]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH [MaxLength]
          ,   CAST(c.NUMERIC_PRECISION as integer) [Precision]
          ,   CAST(c.DATETIME_PRECISION as integer)[DateTimePrecision]
          ,   CAST(c.NUMERIC_SCALE as integer) [Scale]
          ,   c.COLLATION_CATALOG [CollationCatalog]
          ,   c.COLLATION_SCHEMA [CollationSchema]
          ,   c.COLLATION_NAME [CollationName]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG [CharacterSetCatalog]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA [CharacterSetSchema]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_NAME [CharacterSetName]
          ,   CAST(0 as bit) as [IsMultiSet]
          ,   CAST(columnproperty( object_id(quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''.'' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)), c.COLUMN_NAME, ''IsIdentity'' ) as bit) as [IsIdentity]
          ,   CAST(columnproperty( object_id(quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''.'' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)), c.COLUMN_NAME, ''IsComputed'' ) | CASE WHEN c.DATA_TYPE = ''timestamp'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit) as [IsStoreGenerated]
          , c.COLUMN_DEFAULT as [Default]
          FROM
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
          INNER JOIN
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t ON
          c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG AND
          c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA   AND
          c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME       AND
          t.TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE''
      ) AS [Extent2]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent3].[Ordinal] AS [Ordinal], 
    [Extent3].[IsNullable] AS [IsNullable], 
    [Extent3].[TypeName] AS [TypeName], 
    [Extent3].[MaxLength] AS [MaxLength], 
    [Extent3].[Precision] AS [Precision], 
    [Extent3].[DateTimePrecision] AS [DateTimePrecision], 
    [Extent3].[Scale] AS [Scale], 
    [Extent3].[IsIdentity] AS [IsIdentity], 
    [Extent3].[IsStoreGenerated] AS [IsStoreGenerated], 
    6 AS [C1], 
    [Extent3].[ParentId] AS [ParentId]
    FROM (
          SELECT
          quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME) + quotename(c.COLUMN_NAME) [Id]
          ,   quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)                             [ParentId]
          ,   c.COLUMN_NAME   [Name]
          ,   c.ORDINAL_POSITION [Ordinal]
          ,   CAST( CASE c.IS_NULLABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN 1 WHEN ''NO'' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END as bit) [IsNullable]
          ,   CASE
          WHEN c.DATA_TYPE in (''varchar'', ''nvarchar'', ''varbinary'') and
          c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN
          c.DATA_TYPE + ''(max)''
          ELSE
          c.DATA_TYPE
          END
          as [TypeName]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH [MaxLength]
          ,   CAST(c.NUMERIC_PRECISION as integer) [Precision]
          ,   CAST(c.DATETIME_PRECISION as integer) as [DateTimePrecision]
          ,   CAST(c.NUMERIC_SCALE as integer) [Scale]
          ,   c.COLLATION_CATALOG [CollationCatalog]
          ,   c.COLLATION_SCHEMA [CollationSchema]
          ,   c.COLLATION_NAME [CollationName]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG [CharacterSetCatalog]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA [CharacterSetSchema]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_NAME [CharacterSetName]
          ,   CAST(0 as bit) as [IsMultiSet]
          ,   CAST(columnproperty( object_id(quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''.'' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)), c.COLUMN_NAME, ''IsIdentity'' ) as bit) as [IsIdentity]
          ,   CAST(columnproperty( object_id(quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''.'' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)), c.COLUMN_NAME, ''IsComputed'' ) | CASE WHEN c.DATA_TYPE = ''timestamp'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit) as [IsStoreGenerated]
          ,   c.COLUMN_DEFAULT [Default]
          FROM
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
          INNER JOIN
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS v ON
          c.TABLE_CATALOG = v.TABLE_CATALOG AND
          c.TABLE_SCHEMA = v.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
          c.TABLE_NAME = v.TABLE_NAME
          WHERE
          NOT (v.TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo''
          AND v.TABLE_NAME in(''syssegments'', ''sysconstraints'')
          AND SUBSTRING(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(''productversion'') as varchar(20)),1,1) = 8)
      ) AS [Extent3]) AS [UnionAll1] ON (0 = [UnionAll1].[C1]) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = [UnionAll1].[ParentId])
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [UnionAll2].[Id] AS [C1], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C2]
    FROM  (
        SELECT
        quotename(tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA) + quotename(tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME) [Id]
        , quotename(tc.TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(tc.TABLE_NAME) [ParentId]
        ,   tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME [Name]
        ,   tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE [ConstraintType]
        ,   CAST(CASE tc.IS_DEFERRABLE WHEN ''NO'' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as bit) [IsDeferrable]
        ,   CAST(CASE tc.INITIALLY_DEFERRED WHEN ''NO'' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as bit) [IsInitiallyDeferred]
        FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
        WHERE tc.TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
      ) AS [Extent4]
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT 
        7 AS [C1], 
        [Extent5].[ConstraintId] AS [ConstraintId], 
        [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id]
        FROM  (
        SELECT
        quotename(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA) + quotename(CONSTRAINT_NAME) [ConstraintId]
        ,   quotename(TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(TABLE_NAME) + quotename(COLUMN_NAME) [ColumnId]
        FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
      ) AS [Extent5]
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT
          quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME) + quotename(c.COLUMN_NAME) [Id]
          ,   quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)                             [ParentId]
          ,   c.COLUMN_NAME   [Name]
          ,   c.ORDINAL_POSITION [Ordinal]
          ,   CAST( CASE c.IS_NULLABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN 1 WHEN ''NO'' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END as bit) [IsNullable]
          ,   CASE
          WHEN c.DATA_TYPE in (''varchar'', ''nvarchar'', ''varbinary'') and
          c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN
          c.DATA_TYPE + ''(max)''
          ELSE
          c.DATA_TYPE
          END
          as [TypeName]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH [MaxLength]
          ,   CAST(c.NUMERIC_PRECISION as integer) [Precision]
          ,   CAST(c.DATETIME_PRECISION as integer)[DateTimePrecision]
          ,   CAST(c.NUMERIC_SCALE as integer) [Scale]
          ,   c.COLLATION_CATALOG [CollationCatalog]
          ,   c.COLLATION_SCHEMA [CollationSchema]
          ,   c.COLLATION_NAME [CollationName]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG [CharacterSetCatalog]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA [CharacterSetSchema]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_NAME [CharacterSetName]
          ,   CAST(0 as bit) as [IsMultiSet]
          ,   CAST(columnproperty( object_id(quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''.'' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)), c.COLUMN_NAME, ''IsIdentity'' ) as bit) as [IsIdentity]
          ,   CAST(columnproperty( object_id(quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''.'' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)), c.COLUMN_NAME, ''IsComputed'' ) | CASE WHEN c.DATA_TYPE = ''timestamp'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit) as [IsStoreGenerated]
          , c.COLUMN_DEFAULT as [Default]
          FROM
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
          INNER JOIN
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t ON
          c.TABLE_CATALOG = t.TABLE_CATALOG AND
          c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA   AND
          c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME       AND
          t.TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE''
      ) AS [Extent6] ON [Extent6].[Id] = [Extent5].[ColumnId]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        11 AS [C1], 
        [Extent7].[ConstraintId] AS [ConstraintId], 
        [Extent8].[Id] AS [Id]
        FROM  (
        SELECT
        CAST(NULL as nvarchar(1))     [ConstraintId]
        , CAST(NULL as nvarchar(max)) [ColumnId]  
        WHERE 1=2
      ) AS [Extent7]
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT
          quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME) + quotename(c.COLUMN_NAME) [Id]
          ,   quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)                             [ParentId]
          ,   c.COLUMN_NAME   [Name]
          ,   c.ORDINAL_POSITION [Ordinal]
          ,   CAST( CASE c.IS_NULLABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN 1 WHEN ''NO'' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END as bit) [IsNullable]
          ,   CASE
          WHEN c.DATA_TYPE in (''varchar'', ''nvarchar'', ''varbinary'') and
          c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN
          c.DATA_TYPE + ''(max)''
          ELSE
          c.DATA_TYPE
          END
          as [TypeName]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH [MaxLength]
          ,   CAST(c.NUMERIC_PRECISION as integer) [Precision]
          ,   CAST(c.DATETIME_PRECISION as integer) as [DateTimePrecision]
          ,   CAST(c.NUMERIC_SCALE as integer) [Scale]
          ,   c.COLLATION_CATALOG [CollationCatalog]
          ,   c.COLLATION_SCHEMA [CollationSchema]
          ,   c.COLLATION_NAME [CollationName]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG [CharacterSetCatalog]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA [CharacterSetSchema]
          ,   c.CHARACTER_SET_NAME [CharacterSetName]
          ,   CAST(0 as bit) as [IsMultiSet]
          ,   CAST(columnproperty( object_id(quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''.'' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)), c.COLUMN_NAME, ''IsIdentity'' ) as bit) as [IsIdentity]
          ,   CAST(columnproperty( object_id(quotename(c.TABLE_SCHEMA) + ''.'' + quotename(c.TABLE_NAME)), c.COLUMN_NAME, ''IsComputed'' ) | CASE WHEN c.DATA_TYPE = ''timestamp'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit) as [IsStoreGenerated]
          ,   c.COLUMN_DEFAULT [Default]
          FROM
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
          INNER JOIN
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS v ON
          c.TABLE_CATALOG = v.TABLE_CATALOG AND
          c.TABLE_SCHEMA = v.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
          c.TABLE_NAME = v.TABLE_NAME
          WHERE
          NOT (v.TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo''
          AND v.TABLE_NAME in(''syssegments'', ''sysconstraints'')
          AND SUBSTRING(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(''productversion'') as varchar(20)),1,1) = 8)
      ) AS [Extent8] ON [Extent8].[Id] = [Extent7].[ColumnId]) AS [UnionAll2] ON (7 = [UnionAll2].[C1]) AND ([Extent4].[Id] = [UnionAll2].[ConstraintId])
    WHERE [Extent4].[ConstraintType] = N''PRIMARY KEY'' ) AS [Project5] ON [UnionAll1].[Id] = [Project5].[C1]
WHERE  NOT ([Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p0)',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'__RefactorLog'
```

Comment: MS have been changing the cardinality estimator recently starting with Sql Server 2014, which depending on how the procedures are built and utilized could have an impact - I know it did with us until we rewrote some of our stored procedures. Maybe that has an impact? When you attach Sql Server Profiler, what do the generated queries look like? It might be a good idea to revise your database schema and models.

Comment: @user1666620 See my update in question.

Comment: And when you run that script directly on the SQL Server 2016 DB, do you get the same performance issue? If you run it on a different version of SQL server, do you get the same performance drop?

Comment: Yes and yes. I had executed the script directly in SSMS. 2012 0,00 seconds, 2016 6,02 seconds.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just ran it against an instance of SQL Server 2016, and the results came back instantly.  Perhaps you'll find something by comparing the execution plans from both versions.

Comment: It spents the most time with 'Clustered Index Seek' and 'Clustered Index Scan'

Comment: if you are using EDMGEN then the accepted answer works a treat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like user1666620 expected, it was a problem with the cardinality estimation of SQL-Server 2014 or later. For the given query it leads to the problem, that the estimation of query results is interpreted wrong. There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Give the the query the following as parameter in the where clause:
   `OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481)` 
   usage:
    `WHERE  NOT ([Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p0) OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481)',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'__RefactorLog'`
2. Disable the "Legacy Cardinality Estimation" on database.

> **Database->Properties->Options->Legacy Cardinality Estimation = ON**

[image]

Comment: Holy Cow!  Changing that setting turned a 12 MINUTE edmgen back to the seconds it SHOULD take!